# How to hash password using bcrypt

Tags: node.js

hash password in node js using bcrypt i tried this but not working 
password1 is variable that contains password from a form.

```
var dt = dateTime.create();
            var d = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
            console.log(d);
            //hash password
            bcrypt.hash(password1, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
                var sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(name,email,DOB,country,Password,cur_date) values('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + dob + "','" + country + "','" + password1 + "','" + d + "');";
                db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log("successfullt inserted");
                    console.log(result);
                    res.redirect('/');
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the password that you want to hash, don't send `password1` but `hash` (the returned value of bcrypt.hash() function)

Answer (score 0):

You actually used the var that isnt available in the callback scope, you should the hash parameter instead.

Tough you could use the synchronised way to avoid it:

```
var dt = dateTime.create();
var d = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password1, 8);
var sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(name,email,DOB,country,Password,cur_date) values('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + dob + "','" + country + "','" + hashedPassword + "','" + d + "');";
            db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("successfullt inserted");
                console.log(result);
                res.redirect('/');
            });
```

find more here:
https://www.abeautifulsite.net/hashing-passwords-with-nodejs-and-bcrypt